# Iphone-exif 0.91 not working when I add it to my project, gives error ".objc_class_name_EXFJpeg", referenced from:

Tags: iphone

When I add libiphone-exif.a to snapandrun in objectiveflickr I get this error:

```
".objc_class_name_EXFJpeg", referenced from:
literal-pointer@__OBJC@__cls_refs@EXFJpeg in SnapAndRunViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I do not know what this means, I follow the guide to add it, add all of the .h files and the libiphone-exif.a

Is there something special I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you didn't add the library properly.  It is a static library, not an Objective C or data file, so simply adding it to the project isn't enough.  All that will happen is that it gets copied into the application bundle, when it needs to be statically linked into the executable.  You have to open your targets and add the `.a` file under "Link Binary With Libraries".

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the source from the svn project from [google](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-exif/) and drag and drop into my project.

Clicking the target and marking the static lib as "weak" type instead of "required" made no difference.

Comment: Yes it is a static library and I did add it to my target as "Link Binary With Libraries", along with the headers into the project and even made it weak. That should be enough? Also not sure who down graded my answer but I don't think you should downgrade a work around, especially since it is an option in the doc.